# Some questions about S.Roman, "Advanced Linear Algebra"

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, modules, book-recommendation

Question for those who have studied Roman's book "Advanced Linear Algebra".
How self-contained is this book. Can I study determinants directly from this in context of exterior algebra and tensor products?

How much one can understand if he didn't have a previous course in Linear Algebra.

I want to study linear algebra but I want to do it properly with focus in abstract algebra. That is, I want the book to talk about modules, tensor products, exterior algebras.

I tried Blyth's "Module theory - an approach to linear algebra" and Winitzki's "Linear Algebra via Exterior Products", but it didn't work out very well. Not beause the material was too hard, but because I simply don't like the style. It's not fully rigorous.
Now I hope I can learn something from Roman's book.

Answer (score 3):

Well I think the book is quite self-contained. Probably you won’t need to take a pre-course when studying the book since the book has covered the topics quite rigorously and explicitly.

For example, chapter $0$ covers the topics on some basic cardinal arithmetic and the author immediately applies it in the proof of some dimension equations in chapter $1$.

And comments in the book provide an insight into the definition which is appreciated by me. See for example in tensors.

Comment: Chapter 0 is greatly recommended!